# How do I fix "Package amsthm Warning: The \qedhere command..." after redefining align* environment

Tags: horizontal-alignment, align, amsmath

The following MWE

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsthm}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\cs_set_eq:cc { oldalign* }{ align* }
\cs_set_eq:cc { endoldalign* }{ endalign* }
\cs_set:cpn { endalign* }{ \endoldalign }

\RenewDocumentEnvironment{ align* }{ +b }
  { \begin{oldalign*} #1 \end{oldalign*}}
  {}

\ExplSyntaxOff

\begin{document}
\begin{proof}
  \begin{align*}
    a + b &= c \qedhere
  \end{align*}
\end{proof}
\end{document}
```

results in the warning

```
Package amsthm Warning: The \qedhere command may not work correctly here on inp
ut line 22.
```

and causes problems with the horizontal spacing of the qed symbol:

[image]

how do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The warning is issued when `\qedhere` appears in an environment `foo` such that `foo@qed` is not defined.

Add

```
\cs_new_eq:cc { oldalign*qed } { align@qed }
```

How do I know it? Simple, I looked in `amsthm.sty` for the warning message, finding

```
\def\qed@warning{%
  \PackageWarning{amsthm}{The \@nx\qedhere command may not work
    correctly here}%
}
```

OK, look for `\qed@warning`, then:

```
\@ifpackageloaded{amsmath}{%
  \def\math@qedhere{%
    \@ifundefined{\@currenvir @qed}{%
      \qed@warning\quad\hbox{\qedsymbol}%
    }{%
      \@xp\aftergroup\csname\@currenvir @qed\endcsname
    }%
  }
[...]
  \@xp\let\csname align*@qed\endcsname\align@qed
[...]
```

Now I know a bit of the LaTeX internals to know that `\@currenvir` is the name of the current environment LaTeX is in, so I deduce that definitions for `\align@qed` and similar are needed. Another quick look shows that `\align*@qed` is defined (with `\csname`, of course) to be the same as `\align@qed`.